# Xcode constraint issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout, ios-universal-app

Here I have an Image talking the top half of the view and three buttons spaced out in the bottom half of the view. I am unable to get all devices to look the same, on smaller devices the image is dwarfed by the buttons and 4.7 inches and above the image is much larger than the buttons.

What auto-layout constraints should I apply and what size class? 
This app is universal.

[image]

Comment: How do you want the image and the three buttons laid out in the different sizes. If you tell me this, I can help you with the constraints.

Comment: @GaneshKamath I would like the the image to stay in the top half and buttons to stay in the bottom half for all sizes. So the larger the screen size, the more the elements get enlarged and the spacings transform accordingly.

Comment: If you want to have proportional sizeing (so the buttons gets enlarged with the bigger screen) than add the constrinat "equal widths/heights" from container view to the button. Then use the multiplier parameter. ie: for width use 0.6. To keep even distance between the controls create placeholder UIViews between the elements and set them "equal height" and make them hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use size class concept. (Adoptive layout)
For more details visit this
http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10738754)

Comment: You have to make constraints between your objects. And also the size of the objects. On that tutorial you can get the proper information of it so i will share that with you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below constraints for each of the item and you should be good to go :

```
height
width
top
left
right
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input however I found an alternative that is much simpler.

I placed two Views on the storyboard each taking up half of the space ( one is blue for visualisation)then applied the obvious constraints and on each view and treated each view like half of the screen.

Also aspect ratio was necessary for the buttons.

[image]

Comment: Cool. I was doing the same thing, but you answered before I completed. :P

Comment: It seems quite unconventional to me. Do you think that this would be regarded as acceptable in the eyes of an Xcode veteran? after all it works just fine.

Comment: Unconventional, as in?

Comment: As in It could have been resolved without the two extra views.

Comment: I don't see it as unconventional. When I started with auto layout even I felt the same thing as you feel now, but I don't feel that way now a days. The extra two views are required to layout according to what you need. Also, those two extra views won't effect the app performance anyways.

Comment: But, you can achieve it without those two extra views if you need.